# How can I show images in cell?

Tags: ios

I have `TableViewController`  and  `ViewController`. In `viewcontroller` I have Integer (index ==1 , index==2 , index==3) index matches table row in `TableViewController`. In `TableViewController` I have 3 cell with image. Image in cell should show if cell selected and number index in view controller equal number row in `TableViewController`. How can I do it?

ViewController.m

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
if (_index == 0) {
if (_TextField.text.length == 0) {
_TextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
_TextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
_TextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
_TextField.clipsToBounds = YES;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];

}
else if (_Level == 0 && [_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"1"]){
_Level = 1;
_intForString = _intForString + 1;
[self questions];}
else if (_Level == 0 && ![_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
_Level = 1;
_TextField.text = nil;
[self questions];
}
if (_index == 1) {
if (_TextField.text.length == 0) {
_TextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
_TextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
_TextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
_TextField.clipsToBounds = YES;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];

}
else if (_Level == 0 && [_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"2"]){
_Level = 1;
_intForString = _intForString + 1;
[self questions];}
else if (_Level == 0 && ![_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
_Level = 1;
_TextField.text = nil;
[self questions];
}
if (_index == 2) {
if (_TextField.text.length == 0) {
_TextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
_TextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
_TextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
_TextField.clipsToBounds = YES;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];

}
else if (_Level == 0 && [_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"3"]){
_Level = 1;
_intForString = _intForString + 1;
[self questions];}
else if (_Level == 0 && ![_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
_Level = 1;
_TextField.text = nil;
[self questions];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_intForString forKey:@"level"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: _index = 0 forKey: @"_index0"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: _index = 1 forKey: @"_index1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: _index = 2 forKey: @"_index2"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

TableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([self isAvailableRow: indexPath.row]){
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteGreen];
}else{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithGreen:0.95 alpha:1];
}


NSString *level =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"level"];
int intForStrin =[level intValue];
NSString *level0 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"_index0"];
int index0 =[level0 intValue];
NSString *level1 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"_index1"];
int index1 =[level1 intValue];
NSString *level2 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"_index2"];
int index2 =[level2 intValue];



    if (indexPath.row == 0 && index0 == 0 && intForStrin == 1) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 0 && index0 == 0 && intForStrin == 3) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
    }


    else if (indexPath.row == 1 && index1 == 1 && intForStrin == 1) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1 && index1 == 1 && intForStrin == 3) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

if I fulfills the conditions `else if (indexPath.row == 1 && index1 == 1 && intForStrin == 1)` Image shown in first and second table cell. But image should appear only in the second cell.

Comment: i don't really understand your question. why you have to save your index in difference value?

Comment: Because I want to show  1 image  if (indexPath.row == 0 && index1 == 0) and second image if (indexPath.row == 1 && index1 == 1)

Comment: pls check my answer. I think I understand your follow. And your code made it more complicated. Hope this help!

Comment: Is the data comes from the server. Create a data model for the data to display the details including images on the cell. for loading the image use dispatch queue.

Answer (score 2):

You can create new NSMutalbeArray:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *indexArray;
```

then add your index to this array.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (_index == 0) {
        if (_TextField.text.length == 0) {
            _TextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
            _TextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
            _TextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            _TextField.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];

        }
        else if (_Level == 0 && [_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"1"]){
            _Level = 1;
            _intForString = _intForString + 1;
            [self questions];}
        else if (_Level == 0 && ![_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            _Level = 1;
            _TextField.text = nil;
            [self questions];
        }
        if (_index == 1) {
            if (_TextField.text.length == 0) {
                _TextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
                _TextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
                _TextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
                _TextField.clipsToBounds = YES;
                [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp:)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:NO];

            }
            else if (_Level == 0 && [_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"2"]){
                _Level = 1;
                _intForString = _intForString + 1;
                [self questions];}
            else if (_Level == 0 && ![_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
                _Level = 1;
                _TextField.text = nil;
                [self questions];
            }
            if (_index == 2) {
                if (_TextField.text.length == 0) {
                    _TextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
                    _TextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
                    _TextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
                    _TextField.clipsToBounds = YES;
                    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp:)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:NO];

                }
                else if (_Level == 0 && [_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"3"]){
                    _Level = 1;
                    _intForString = _intForString + 1;
                    [self questions];}
                else if (_Level == 0 && ![_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
                    _Level = 1;
                    _TextField.text = nil;
                    [self questions];
                }

                self.indexArray = [NSMutableArray new];
                [self.indexArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_intForString]];
                [self.indexArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_index]];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in TableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self isAvailableRow: indexPath.row]){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteGreen];
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithGreen:0.95 alpha:1];
    }



    int intForStrin =[[self.indexArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    int index = [[self.indexArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue]


    if (indexPath.row == 0 && index == 0 && intForStrin == 1) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 0 && index == 0 && intForStrin == 3) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
    }


    else if (indexPath.row == 1 && index == 1 && intForStrin == 1) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1 && index == 1 && intForStrin == 3) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```